# Easy way to simulate Invalid Viewstate?

Tags: asp.net, viewstate

Is there an *easy* way to simulate Invalid Viewstate?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sure: just add a simple javascript function to the page to modify the hidden __VIEWSTATE input.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [fiddler](http://www.fiddlertool.com/fiddler/)

It can simulate a postback very easily and you can modify that post.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a jQuery way to implement Joel's suggestion:

```
<script language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('input[@name=__VIEWSTATE]').val("this is now bad");
});
```